# React import statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am confused about what is going on with React `import` statements under the hood.

A classic example I have seen imports things from the `ReactRouterDOM` like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

[Here is a working example I found on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpp7pl79wm)

However, there is something going on under the hood here because I can't figure out how to create a simple html file and script which uses this syntax. It seems that you are somehow forced to use the 'create react' scripts if you want to use that syntax. Meanwhile, if I switch the syntax to:

```
const {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Link
} = ReactRouterDOM;
```

Then I can create a really simple [static html file which uses the react router DOM](https://codepen.io/mholzel/pen/BqvaLo).

Could somebody explain the difference with these syntaxes? Everybody seems to use the first version, but the second version seems to be working much more intuitively to me.

Comment: The first version is when your using a module loader, the second version I'm assume your including React using a `<script src="">`

Comment: Correct. I am using a script inside the html.

Comment: I want to create a static site that minimizes server side code.

Comment: `I want to create a static site that minimizes server side code.` That's what using modules and webpack does though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...I can't figure out how to create a simple html file and script which uses this syntax...

You can't, using **exactly** that syntax, because that module specifier isn't currently supported on the web. It works in a React project presumably because a bundler is involved.

To use native module support on the web:

1. Include your entry-point script using a `type="module"` `script` tag.
2. Use `import` statements in that entry-point to reference other scripts:

   - From the same location: `from "./mod.js"` — note that the `./` is required.
   - In the parent of the current location: `from ../mod.js`
   - At the root of yoru domain: `from "/mod.js"`

   For now, module specifiers in browsers must start with `./`, `../`, or `/`.

Here's a simple example that works on modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge) without a bundler:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Module Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
import { example } from "./mod.js";

example();
```

`mod.js`:

```
export function example() {
    console.log("Hello, modules!");
}
```

When you load the HTML page, it will load `main.js`, which will in turn load `mod.js`.

In that example, `example` is a *named export* of `mod.js`, which is why you import it with `{ example }`.

Modules can also (or instead) have a *default export*:

```
export default function() {
    console.log("Hello, modules!");
}
```

You import the default without `{}`:

```
import example from "./mod.js";
```

Comment: Ia it somehow bad practice or dangerous to use the second approach? I really do not find that syntax anywhere in React tutorials, but it is really convenient for me

Comment: @bremen_matt - You mean the destructuring example in your question? It's fine. It's a big old-school, but it's fine. :-) Or better yet, use a bundler.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I mean the second approach I provide.

Comment: @bremen_matt - As I say, it's fine. Probably woth noting that although named imports and destructuring look similar, named imports *aren't* destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the differences between javascript standards and their support.

What you try to achieve is called destructing:
[Object Rest / Spread Properties](https://derickbailey.com/2017/06/06/3-features-of-es7-and-beyond-that-you-should-be-using-now/)

This is a feature of  ES2018 (ES9). In order to use the syntax you need to transpile the code to standard js (or supported by the engine)

I think the react-scripts do that by default in their project config. So you can do that also. Just need to learn to use webpack for instance with babel.

Comment: should be noted: named imports/exports and destructing _look_ similar, but are not the same.